# ASP.NET MVC Scaffolding View - Missing Model Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my first time with MVC so please excuse me if I am getting the terminology wrong.  I am working on a PluralSight course.

My understanding is scaffolding goes to the model and creates a view when selecting Add View.

Here's my model

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace OdeToFood.Models
    {
        public class RestaurantReview
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }        
            public int Rating { get; set; }
            public string Body { get; set; }
            public string ReviewerName { get; internal set; }
            public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

        }
  }
```

I go to my controller action and click Add View.  My view is missing ReviewerName when it is built.  I add ReviewerName manually to my Create view.  The ReviewerName appears to not be recognized by the Model Binder when data is added to the database.

I am unsure where to go from here.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Try switching "internal set" to just "set". That may be hiding it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149630/why-default-asp-scaffolding-skips-some-of-the-model-properties-while-generating

Comment: I could've sworn I changed the property before posting.  That was it!

Thank you.

Comment: Also, how do I mark the question complete?  I looked for a check mark but don't see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mark the property setter as internal, the scaffolding ignores it. Simply remove that from the property and you should be set (pun intended):

```
public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
```